# socks 5 proxy on Perl

Tags: perl, proxy, client, socks

I am new in Perl and trying to understand this cod in Link : http://codepaste.ru/1374/but I have some problem in understanding this part of code:

```
while($client || $target) {
  my $rin = "";
  vec($rin, fileno($client), 1) = 1 if $client;
  vec($rin, fileno($target), 1) = 1 if $target;
  my($rout, $eout);
  select($rout = $rin, undef, $eout = $rin, 120);
  if (!$rout  &&  !$eout) { return; }
  my $cbuffer = "";
  my $tbuffer = "";

  if ($client && (vec($eout, fileno($client), 1) || vec($rout, fileno($client), 1))) {
    my $result = sysread($client, $tbuffer, 1024);
    if (!defined($result) || !$result) { return; }
  }

  if ($target  &&  (vec($eout, fileno($target), 1)  || vec($rout, fileno($target), 1))) {
    my $result = sysread($target, $cbuffer, 1024);
    if (!defined($result) || !$result) { return; }
    }

  if ($fh  &&  $tbuffer) { print $fh $tbuffer; }

  while (my $len = length($tbuffer)) {
    my $res = syswrite($target, $tbuffer, $len);
    if ($res > 0) { $tbuffer = substr($tbuffer, $res); } else { return; }
  }

  while (my $len = length($cbuffer)) {
    my $res = syswrite($client, $cbuffer, $len);
    if ($res > 0) { $cbuffer = substr($cbuffer, $res); } else { return; }
  }
}
```

can any body explain to me exactly whats happen in these lines:

```
vec($rin, fileno($client), 1) = 1 if $client;
vec($rin, fileno($target), 1) = 1 if $target;
```

and

```
select($rout = $rin, undef, $eout = $rin, 120);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the `select` operator is used to find which of your file descriptors are ready (readable, writable or there's an error condition). It will wait until one of the file descriptors is ready, or timeout.

```
select RBITS, WBITS, EBITS, TIMEOUT
```

`RBITS` is a bit mask, usually stored as a string, representing a set of file descriptors that `select` will wait for readability. Each bit of `RBITS` represent a file descriptor, and the offset of the file descriptor in this bit mask should the file descriptor number in system. Thus, you could use `vec` to generate this bit mask.

```
vec EXPR, OFFSET, BITS
```

The `vec` function provides storage of lists of unsigned integers. `EXPR` is a bit string, `OFFSET` is the offset of bit in `EXPR`, and `BITS` specifies the width of each element you're reading from / writing to `EXPR`.

So these 2 lines:

```
vec($rin, fileno($client), 1) = 1;
vec($rin, fileno($target), 1) = 1;
```

They made up a bit mask string `$rin` with setting the bit whose offset equals the file descriptor number of `$client`, as well as the one of `$target`.

Put it into `select` operator:

```
select($rout = $rin, undef, $eout = $rin, 120);
```

Then `select` will monitor the readability of the two file handlers (`$client` and `$target`), if one of them is ready, `select` will return. Or it will return after 120s if no one is ready.

`WBITS`, `EBITS` use the same methodology. So you could infer that the above `select` line will also return when the two file handler have any exceptions.